# Registration while using Firebase is not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make registration while using google firebase but it is not working. During this, Dialogue box continuously loading and nothing is happening even after couple of minutes.
I have added internet connection in AndroidMenifests.xml and also Enable Email/Password auth on firebase console.

What should i do to make it working?

> Here,s my MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //initializing views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        Button buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //attaching listener to button
        buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void registerUser(){

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        registerUser();

    }
}
```

> Here I set up following dependencies in **app.gradle** file

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
//cloud dep
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and **build.gradle** file

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

> Here's AndroidManifests.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.irfan.reg">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[That's my Logcat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7In0.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Any logcats? Also, did you enabled email/password authentication on the console? You can however try to add `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3` **before any firebase dependencies** at the top of the dependencies. This might help

Comment: Do you get `"Registration Error"`?  Have you tried ti add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'` to your dependecies? Please reponde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo We use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth` for the Google + sign in as you know and inside the OP codes, there is no such related codes to google+ sign in and it's just an email/password login.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท - I tried your way but still the problem is same.

Comment: @AlexMamo -  I also tried your way but the problem is same.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Oh, I thought I saw something related with Google but it's just a simple email/password authentication. You're right, thanks!

Comment: @IrfanAkram That wasn't actually a way. Please give us logcat error or anything related. Also, do you get any Toasts? like succesful or error or something?

Comment: I updated question as well.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท - I provided logact image by updating question, you can check at the end of code. And i doesn't get any toast because loading never ends. Thanks!

Comment: Logs didn't help (Suspicious errors can be found started by firebase tho). Can you try removing `trim()` from both editTextEmail and editTextPassword then checking? That's weird. How about the console? Is email/password enabled?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท - nothing happening. And email/password is enabled

Comment: So, there might be internet connection issue or, Not enabled email/pass authentication from https://console.firebase.google.com Also, you'll need to make a project in there too (From firebase console). However, would you paste your `AndroidManifest.xml` codes too?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท - I updated question and added AndroidManifest.xml. Also I had created a new project on console.firebase.google for some other task and in this existing project I added a new App for registration project (current discussing). <br>
I think it should not be a problem to add a new app in an existing project. Can it be?

Comment: Great.(No problem with the internet connection). It seems like there is a problem when connecting to internet since you said `progressDialog` not closes. There must be some errors in your logcat tho. However, this is pretty weird and you should check your android studio with the internet connection first.

Comment: Show your list of logcat

Comment: @AngusTay - Already provided logact image below AndroidManifest.xml file's code. you can check there.

Comment: I mean more of it, the image just showing meaningless log

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here's how you may want to change your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKd9N.png)

Hello my friend.  I noticed there was some issue with your onclick method.  I removed it and placed in a standard setOnClickListener in its' place and everything works just fine.  Let me know if this helps.

---

Also if you'd like to keep your onClick method just remove the override tag and add the onClick method in the xml.

this is what your buttons xml should look like now.

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSignup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPassword" />
```

Notice the ' android:onClick="onClick" ' tag that's now in the the tag list.  Hope this helps my friend.

Comment: He has bound the onclicklistener, action can be made with the button now, just that the program seems 'not responding' after onclick.

Comment: I just updated my answer.  He may be missing the tag in the xml.

Comment: It works fine fore me after I created his project and put the tag in the XML

Comment: NO ITS NOT! I JUST BUILT HIS PROJECT GUYS. IT WORKS!

Comment: @HamzahNajiullah - I had gone with your way, but still have the same issue.
If u have done with this code after made changes then please if possible send updated source code to irfanakram825@gmail.com

Comment: @HamzahNajiullah First, learn to read the question and code.  Then, learn problem solving skill, identify the problem before you giving out solution.  Try to accept others' advises.  You will never improve if you are mind-blocked

Comment: @AngusTay Okay. Good advise.  So what's the problem.  Because I ran his code, adjusted it and it works fine for me.  So I'm asking. What do you see is his solution?